# Why doesn't assoc work here to disassociate a file type association?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-10-v2004

I associated a file extension with an app (`.txt2` with `notepad`) by creating a file and naming it `a.txt2`, clicking it, and selecting `notepad` as its default app.

Then I tried to disassociate it from notepad using: `assoc .txt2=`  from an elevated CMD window. [[assoc docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc#examples)]

It changes nothing. Clicking the file still opens it in notepad even after restarting the computer.

Why? Is there some step missing here?

**More info**

Typing `assoc .txt2` to check its associations returns:

> File association not found for extension .txt2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assoc` command is very old, dating from DOS, and does not use well the
newer file-association mechanism of Windows.

The proof is that after running `assoc .txt2=notepad`,
double-click on a `.txt2` file does not launch `notepad`,
so you need to still specify the default app.
The opposite is also true: Running `assoc .txt2=` is not enough to undo
the newer mechanism.

Searching the registry finds that the command `assoc .txt2=notepad` only sets
the registry keys `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.txt2` and `HKCR\.txt2`, which are
deleted by `assoc .txt2=`.

However, setting the default association through Explorer with "always use"
creates keys chiefly under `HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt2`
and some others.

This is why `assoc .txt2=` cannot undo the assignment through Explorer,
as it doesn't know about these new registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove by **`assoc`** and `file type=`

```bat
assoc .txt2=
ftype text2=
```

- This will remove the entries associated with your **`.txt2`** extension, you don't need to do this manually

```bat
HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt2
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.txt2
```

- When it is necessary to create again, use:

```bat
assoc .txt2=text2
ftype text2=%windir%\notepad.exe "%1"
```

- **`ftype`** in **[ms docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype)**